# qmake Makefile does not include a dependency on ui_form.h in rule for myWidget.o

Tags: qt4, makefile, qmake

My setup:
I am creating and updating a *form.ui* file in *Qt Designer*, and using the *Makefile* generated by `qmake`. Using *form.ui*, `make` correctly generates *ui_form.h*, which is included in *myWidget.cc*.

The problem:
When *form.ui* is updated, `make` correspondingly regenerates *ui_form.h*. However, *myWidget.o* is not regenerated and thus the UI updates are not reflected in the recompiled application. On inspecting the *Makefile*, it turns out that the *myWidget.o* rule has no dependency on *ui_form.h*.

The question:
How can I force `qmake` to include the required dependency in the *Makefile* it generates?
Note: As the *Makefile* is auto-generated each time `qmake` is run, a manual edit of the *Makefile* is only a temporary solution which I would rather avoid.

Related:
-- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616932/qt-gui-doesnt-change-after-compilation) identifies a similar problem but is still open. The replies do not sufficiently explore the problem (narrow it down to the missing *Makefile* dependency) and the solutions given do not work.
-- There is a discussion on adding dependencies to the *Makefile* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434707/is-it-possible-to-add-a-dependency-to-your-makefile-in-qmake) but this question, too, is still open and the scenario is different from mine.

Comment: Have you re-run qmake to re-generate the makefile?  I have in the past had issues where I changed the code just enough to require a re-run of qmake, but not quite enough to cause the old makefile to trigger the re-run.  (I don't remember exactly how I did it, though.)

Comment: And does your myWidget.cc actually #include, directly or indirectly, ui_form.h, in order for qmake to have a dependency to detect?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the problem that the myWidget.o rule did not list ui_form.h as a dependency in the makefile. In my case ui_form.h was an indirect dependency (myWidget.h includes ui_form.h).

For Qmake to generate makefiles that include header files as dependencies (direct or indirect inclusion), the [INCLUDEPATH](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#includepath) and [DEPENDPATH](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#dependpath) need to be properly set ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6184053)).

**Makefile**

```
release/tmp/myWidget.o: src/source/myWidget.cpp src/source/myWidget.h
        $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o release/tmp/myWidget.o src/source/myWidget.cpp
```

**Project.pro**

```
INCLUDEPATH += src/header
DEPENDPATH += src/header

CONFIG += debug_and_release

CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
     DESTDIR      = debug
     RCC_DIR      = debug/tmp
     OBJECTS_DIR  = debug/tmp
     UI_DIR       = debug/tmp
     MOC_DIR      = debug/tmp
     INCLUDEPATH += debug/tmp
     DEPENDPATH  += debug/tmp
} else {
     DESTDIR      = release
     RCC_DIR      = release/tmp
     OBJECTS_DIR  = release/tmp
     UI_DIR       = release/tmp
     MOC_DIR      = release/tmp
     INCLUDEPATH += release/tmp
     DEPENDPATH  += release/tmp
}
```

**Makefile**

```
release/tmp/myWidget.o: src/source/myWidget.cpp src/source/myWidget.h \
                        release/tmp/ui_form.h
        $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o release/tmp/myWidget.o src/source/myWidget.cpp
```